# Add columns from table 2 to columns at table1 based on Id matches (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and after performing certain calculations, i select the columns of the temp table to display at the UI.

Here is the end part of that stored procedure

```
SELECT Id, Data, Value from #preopt
```

The data which returns when we run this select statement is as follows.

```
 Id   |  Data  |  Value
 1    |  xyz   |   232
 2    |  abc   |   222
 3    |  3232  |   www
```

Now I have one more table. This is not a temporary table. It has following data in it.

SELECT Id, List1, List2 from dbo.IdLists

```
Id    |  List1   |  List2 
1     |   g23    |   h323
45    |   g21    |   h44
2     |   g455   |   g45
3     |   g32    |   h48
```

I want my final table from stored proc to look like this. In the temp table #preopt. Basically it checks the Id column in #preopt and compares with Id column in dbo.IDlists. After comparison, it picks up List1 & List2 columns and adds relevant value for that id to the temp table #preopt

```
 Id   |  Data  |  Value   | List1  | List2
 1    |  xyz   |   232    | g23    |  h323
 2    |  abc   |   222    | g455   |  g45
 3    |  3232  |   www    | g32    |  h48
```

Can someone please let me know if this is achievable?

Comment: Sql Server or MySql ?

Comment: AllSql I guess, maybe

Comment: SQL Server it is

Comment: Looks like you want a `JOIN`   http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: is it a session table (preopt) ?

Comment: why you use `tat` instead of `That`?

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick. Update your List1 and List2 in the temp table using the values from the join on IDLists.

```
UPDATE p
SET p.List1 = l.List1, p.List2 = l.List2
FROM #preopt p 
INNER JOIN dbo.IdLists l
ON p.Id = l.Id
```

Comment: Op want 4 columns in the result.

Comment: Why would you need to update the 2 values in the table you are selecting from?

Comment: Let me phrase that a different way. You have a temp table with 5 columns, one is ID, two have data, two are NULL. You need to update the 2 NULL values, not 4 values since 2 already have data.

Comment: You dont need `UPDATE` period. Just a `SELECT JOIN`

Comment: You can do whatever you want but the question from the op is this: `After comparision, it picks up List1 & List2 columns and adds relevant value for tat id to the temp table #preopt`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do a join.

```
SELECT po.Id, po.Data, po.Value, il. from #preopt po
INNER JOIN dbo.IdLists il on po.Id = il.Id
```

Comment: very close but you need to fix the field names from IdLists